# Parsing "Return-Path:" in Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email-parsing

What is the best way to parse the mail headers and get the email address in the "return-path" field using Python?

```
Return-Path: <bob@example2.com>
Date: Sat, 16 Feb 2013 14:14:32 -0500
Subject: Hello World!
From: Robert Jones <robert.jones@example2.com>
To: Steve <steve@example.com>
```

P.S. I am a bit of a Python n00b and this code will need to run on AppEngine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you probably want to use the stdlib's [`email`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email) package to parse the message.

I'm not sure how you're getting the message—things like the stdlib `imaplib` or the gmail API give you a way to get headers separately from the body, but other methods may give you the entire message. Either way, you can pass the whole thing to the [`email.parser.HeaderParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.parser.html#parser-class-api) to parse the headers and ignore anything else:

```
>>> from email.parser import HeaderParser

>>> msg = HeaderParser().parsestr(header) # or parsestr(msg) if you have the whole msg
>>> return_path = msg.get('Return-Path')
```

Now, `return_path` is the string `"<bob@example2.com>"`, which you can just parse as an email address (or `None`, if there isn't one).

```
>>> from email.utils import parseaddr
>>> realname, emailaddr = parseaddr(return_path)
```

Now, `realname` is `""`, and `emailaddr` is `'bob@example2.com'`.

The reason there are two parts is because this is also perfectly valid:

```
Return-Path: "Bob Example" <bob@example.com>
```

Now, this may not be quite right. Are you allowed to have two `Return-Path` headers? Or can the `Return-Path` header include multiple addresses? I can't remember. I could look it up in the relevant RFCs, but then I'd also have to do some searching to find out whether any popular clients violate these particular rules. I can't remember all of this. So, for convenience, I usually assume anything can be multiple-headers and multiple-values and do things this way:

```
>>> return_paths = msg.get_all('Return-Path')
```

This returns the `list` `["<bob@example2.com>"]`. (If there are no `Return-Path` headers, you'll get an empty `list`, instead of `None`, this way.) And you can just parse that all at once, to get a `list` of name, address pairs instead of just one:

```
>>> from email.utils import getaddresses
>>> for realname, emailaddr in getaddresses(returnpaths):
...     print(realname, emailaddr)
```

And if it turns out that Return-Path only allows a single value, the same code just works as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split()` function and then `strip()`:

```
line = "Return-Path: <bob@example2.com>"
header, value = line.split(":")
value = value.strip()
```

PS If you need to get rid of the braces, just use the strip function again:

```
value = value.strip('<>')
```

Comment: What is the best way to find the "Return-Path" line?

Comment: This is not a good idea, because the actual format is much more complicated than just stripping whitespace and angle brackets will handle. You do not want to learn the format and write a parser for it if you can avoid it. and you can.

Comment: Agreed. This was a rather quick and dirty answer.